# Rails 3 CSV imports to raise errors in resulting view

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A CSV import process intends to import valid records and advise of errors on bad records in a resulting action.

rescue outputs can go to the console, and in development mode rendered to the user.  But in production mode these need to be captured and rendered.

The model defines the import

```
def self.importtest(file, analisi_id)
  n, errs = 0, []
  CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => "\t", headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
    n += 1
    # skip blank row
    next if row.join.blank?

    begin
      operativ = Operativ.find_by_account(row[3])
      if operativ.nil?
        errs << row
      end
    end
  end

  if errs != []
    #  send errors to form and render to user
  else
    #  run full import routine
```

and the controller

```
  def import
    params[:analysis_id] = session[:analysis_id]
    Bilancino.import(params[:file], params[:analysis_id])
    redirect_to loaded_registrations_path, notice: "data imported" 
  end
```

There are two problems here. The first is how to populate a form with the error data.  The second is how to re-direct in each case `errs != []` and `errs == []`...

Comment: Please post the full error message, incluidng the class.  I'm not sure that ```flash[:error]``` is available in Rails models.  If you want errors to show up from controller actions I would be setting the flash method there.  Perhaps by adding the error to an instance of the model object then testing if its ```.valid?``` in your controller to trigger the flash.

Comment: The notion of errors was misconstrued.  I reformulated the question to better reflect the goal

Comment: You don't need to create your own errors object as Rails has an `object.errors` model attribute already for adding them. Its a simple key value hash.  Every key is the name of an attribute (e.g. `:country_code`), and the value is any error message for that field (e.g. `"Invalid country code"`).  You can inspect all errors via `errors[:base]`.  With it in your controller method you can do something like `render :edit and return unless @model_object.valid?`  `.valid?` fails if `object.errors` contains errors. After render, the `errors[:base]` hash will contain errors for displaying to your form.

Comment: It's creating a form with  the errors which is the problem

Comment: My point is that you add the errors into your object. In your controller create a method in your model (```@model_object.check_for_errors```) that checks attributes on the form object that's been submitted, and add custom error messages to the model objects attributes if errors exist.  Then later in your controller ```@model_object.valid?``` will respond correctly based on if errors exist.  The errors hash will have those errors if you render the page, and in your view you can call them to show them.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors